# Fetch API Platform context when path to documentation was moved

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

We have an API Platform v2.7 (Symfony 4.4 application) and a React Admin. We are update documentation path to `/api-docs`. Each application is a standalone project. I was able to achieve this by altering the `api_platform` configuration:

```yaml
enable_swagger_ui: false
enable_re_doc: false
enable_entrypoint: false
```

This way, the default documentation route is disabled and I can access the new documentation at the `/api-docs` path. However, I observed that the initial request done by React Admin is no longer correct. Before I used to receive a JSON response, while now I receive a HTML response, so something is off, but I can't understand what.

And by creating a new route under `config/routes.yaml` as described in their documentation:

```yaml
api_platform_docs:
    path: /api-docs
    controller: api_platform.swagger_ui.action
```

How can I continue to use the new path and still make it behave like before? Did you encounter something like this before?